# Simplify the expression $ \left(\displaystyle \frac{1+i z}{1-iz}\right)^i, i^2=-1. $

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers

Simplify the expression
$$
\left(\frac{1+i z}{1-iz}\right)^i, i^2=-1, z \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Really I have no any good idea to do it.

Comment: Here's a hint: try converting the numerator and denominator to exponential form. i.e $e^{i.\theta}$

Comment: How is "simplified" defined for you? Involving $\arctan (z)$ or $\exp(z)$ does not appear to be simpler than just what we have.

Comment: choosing $z$ as a variable name in $\mathbb R$ where there are complex numbers everywhere is a poor choice (or a sadistic one...).

Comment: zwim I agree :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to polar form, we have

$$1 +iz = \sqrt{1+z^2} e^{i(\arctan z + 2n\pi)}, 1-iz = \sqrt{1+z^2}e^{-i(\arctan z + 2m\pi)}$$

where $n, m$ can be any integers due to the periodicity of the complex exponential.

Since the modulus is the same for both complex numbers, it cancels out in the fraction and we are left with:

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{1+iz}{1-iz}\right)^i &= \left(\frac{e^{i\arctan z}e^{2n\pi i}}{e^{-i\arctan z}e^{2m\pi i}}\right)^i\\
&=\left(e^{2i\arctan z}e^{2i\pi k}\right)^i\\
&=e^{-2(\arctan z +\pi k)}
\end{align}

where $k = n - m$ is also an integer.

Comment: It would be nice not to occult the other solutions when you deal with complex exponential. i.e. factors of $e^{2k\pi}$.

Comment: That's a good point. I've modified my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Tom, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since I've never dealt with complex powers of complex numbers I'm just testing out what I think should happen following Ananthakrishna's advice, please suggest any changes or help fill in the gaps. Here goes-

Rationalizing said expression
$=(\frac{1-z^2+2iz}{1-z^2})^i=(1+i\frac{2z}{1-z^2})^i=r(e^{i\theta})^i=re^{i^2\theta}=re^{-\theta}$

$$where,\  r=\frac{1+z^2}{1-z^2} \ and\ \tan\theta=\frac{2z}{1-z^2} $$

Comment: $(e^{i\theta})^i=e^{i^2\theta}$ requires some justification